# Clarification on Reshaping DataFrame from LONG to WIDE in R with Gather/Spread

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, reshape

I am sorry to come back on a topic that has several threads on Stack, but I am trying to Reshape a dataset from LONG to WIDE, using Tidyverse, and either the Gather/Spread function as well as the pivot_wider function, and I am lost.
Here it is a sample of the subset I am using for test

```
    structure(list(pid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", 
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", 
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", 
"155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", 
"164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", 
"173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", 
"182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", 
"191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", 
"200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", 
"209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216"), class = "factor"), 
    timewave = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), dev_icd = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    lab_bnp = c(388, 199, 387.5, 318, 154, 949.4)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here there the 2 commands I came up to

```
test.wide2 <- test.long2 %>%
          pivot_wider(id_cols = pid, 
                      names_from = timewave, 
                      values_from = c(dev_icd, lab_bnp), 
                      names_sep = "")
```

Or also

```
test.wide <- test.long2 %>%
         group_by(pid) %>%
         gather("dev_icd", "lab_bnp", 
                key = variable, value = number ) %>%
         unite(combi, variable, timewave) %>%
         spread(combi, number)
```

Neither is working as I would expect, I get a lot of NA or NULL values and do not understand what is my mistake and the correct procedure.
Any help not only in fixing the issue but mainly in understanding the Reshaping logic/philosophy would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `Neither is working as I would expect`, what's your expected?

Comment: I am sorry, you (and Merijn) are totally right, I can only say I wrote the post as last optio n, after many many tries and I was hexaust. So I would expct to have PID on a single row (a single row per patient indeed) with dev_icd and lab_bnp repeated (on separated columns) for each timewave, something like PID 1 --> dev_icd.1, dev_icd.2 dev_icd.3 etc, and lab_bnp.1, lab_bnp2 etc...dev_icd and lab_bnp repated as many as timewaves available. Thank you very much for the help and sorry for my uncompleteness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more explicit on what you want, we can only assume. You cannot expect any values that are not present in your widest format. I take a guess here in that you want something like this.

```
test.long2 %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = c("pid", "timewave"), 
    names_from = pid, 
    values_from = c(dev_icd, lab_bnp), 
    names_sep = "_pid")

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  timewave dev_icd_pid1 dev_icd_pid2 lab_bnp_pid1 lab_bnp_pid2
  <fct>    <fct>        <fct>               <dbl>        <dbl>
1 1        No           Yes                  388          949.
2 2        No           NA                   199           NA 
3 3        No           NA                   388.          NA 
4 4        No           NA                   318           NA 
5 5        No           NA                   154           NA
```

Comment: You are totally right Mejin and I am sorry, actually I would need PID on rows (every PID/patient on a different row) and timewave suffix on the columns, so to have dev_icd and lab_bnp repated on different columns for as many timewaves available in the timewave variable....hope to be clearer now. Again thanks a lot for the help, my apologies

Comment: Merjin, I have worked on your code and the following looks encouraging `test.wide <- test.longred %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("pid", "timewave"), 
              names_from = timewave, 
              values_from = c(dev_icd, lab_bnp), 
              names_sep = "_timew")`,   although I get the following Warning message: `Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols`, and this is not completely clear to me...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to help from Merjin van Tiborg, I have finally nailed down the issue. The correct command to have PID on rows and columns for dev-icd and lab_bnp repeated by timewave number is as follows:

```
    test.wide <- hf.longsmall %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("pid", "timewave"), 
              names_from = timewave, 
              values_from = c(dev_icd, lab_bnp), 
              names_sep = "_t")
```

That is equivalent to the following

```
    test.wide1  <- hf.longsmall %>% 
  group_by(pid, timewave) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = timewave, 
                     values_from = c(dev_icd, lab_bnp), 
                     names_sep = "_t") %>%
  select(-row)
```

I have got the following warning --> "Values in `values_from` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols", and that was due to a real (and dangerous) mistake of duplicated PID during data entry. Anyhow, I could understand the issue only using the group_by option reported above.

Thank you all for the patience